# What does ">=?" mean in SQL?

Tags: sql

I came across a line of code in SQL:

```
"SELECT DT FROM TABLE WHERE DT >= ?;"
```

and I'm trying to make sense of the ">=?" ending. DT are a collection of datetimes with some natural ordering so ">=" I would expect to receive an argument of some date, instead the "?" has me confused.

I did some googling using the queries "SQL ">=?" meaning" and "SQL ? constant" but both yielded nothing, glancing through Stackoverflow's suggested answers also yields nothing, and w3schools didn't seem to ever discuss this, so I would like to ask this purely syntax question here.

Comment: The ? is a placeholder for a value. This query is supposed to be completed, for example as a prepared statement.

Comment: *I came across a line of code in SQL* ... please give us more context of where this code was found as that will solve your question. Since it is quoted, likely it originates in an application layer (Java, C#, VB, PHP, Python, R, etc.) to be called on a database as a parameterized query.

Comment: It’s from python, in an application that connects to a SQL database and makes a query, with that string and another argument that I didn’t understand, but now realize to replace the ?. I modified the command to convey the main question and redact anything I thought would reveal more about the application than hopefully what was needed to answer the question, sorry if it came across as too terse

Comment: Then it is a parameterized query. Learn the specific Python API as some use `?` (SQLite) and some use `%s` (MySQL, Postgres, SQL Server) for placeholders.

Answer (score 4):

The `>=` means "greater than or equal to".

The `?` is a placeholder for an anonymous parameter.  This would be used from an application or dynamic SQL.

Comment: Ah I see, so this is a python symbol for string substitution and not native to SQL

Comment: Or perhaps that's wrong, its not python, but whatever is the language being used by my data base cursor, if we were to give a name

Comment: @frogeyedpeas The database provider (also known as the database driver) is typically what does the replacement, so it's typically what determines the syntax of the placeholders.  The `?` syntax is a common syntax among many ODBC providers and other providers which may not support named parameters.